# Every time i try to index my SQLite database it gets locked

Tags: python, sqlite, locking

I have a fairly large SQLite database populated database, where the table I am trying to index have approximately 170m records. In retrospect I should have created the index before I populated it, but that is too late now. Whenever I run my indexing code, which is supplied under, everything goes fine for the first 10 minutes before it gets locked. I am not doing anything with the database while this script runs.

```
con = lite.connect('database/AISdatabase.db')

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE INDEX longitude_index ON MessageType1 (longitude)")
```

Error:

```
  File "indexer.py", line 10, in <module>
    cur.execute("CREATE INDEX longitude_index ON MessageType1 (longitude)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

real    10m14.274s
user    8m41.176s
sys 0m34.562s
```

The reason for that I run this in a python script and not in SQLite is because I get the following error in SQLite3 `Error: no such table: main.MessageType1` (It is only when I try to index I get this error as querying etc goes fine).

Comment: Is the database being used by another process?

Comment: No other connections with the database is being made (as I am aware of atleast). No other script is run on the database, and I havent got any sqlite connection up.